# Check status of a production ASP.NET process

Tags: asp.net, production, strace

Is there a way to check what a asp.net process is doing in production environment?  In Linux, one can run a strace on a process id and know exactly what the process is doing.  Can one do something similar on a asp.net process?  Googling around tells me that you need to create dump files and then analyze the problem there, but what if I just want to check on the current state of the process? (like cache size, longest running thread, # of the specific object... etc).

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If you do not get the answer you are looking for here you should check out http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by JD, PerfMon may help you out.  You should also check out the [Windows Sysinternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx).  The two Sysinternal tools that will probably help you out the most are:

- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
- [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can see most of the information in your question by using PerfMon.

This provides an overview of ASP.Net monitoring with perfmon http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xxk09t8(VS.71).aspx

To see managed memory usage check out .Net Garbage Collector (you can filter it down to the asp.net web site).

Check out the Process counters for more information about the IIS worker process.